# How to show Two Graphs of psych package side by side

Tags: r, psych

The Code below should show Two Identical Graphs side by side. However, it is plotting 2nd graph over the 1st.

```r
library("psych")
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
corPlot(mtcars)
corPlot(mtcars)
```

This is minimum working example. Actual Graphs are different.

Edit: As shown in the answer, following works

```r
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
corPlot(mtcars, show.legend = FALSE, keep.par = FALSE)
corPlot(mtcars, show.legend = FALSE, keep.par = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the help-page from corPlot there is actual a working example two plot several graphs, here  it is adapted for your data:

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
corPlot(mtcars,show.legend=F,keep.par=FALSE,upper=T)
corPlot(mtcars,show.legend=F,keep.par=FALSE,upper=T)
par(op)
```

[image]

Note, that when you change show.legend=T, this does not work.

Comment: Thank You and can't  believe it was given in Help Page !!! I did went through all the options one by one :(

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, whenever it is easy enough for you to switch, you should choose using `ggplot2` over other plotting systems as it is more mature and robust. Here is a solution using `ggplot2` centered packages `ggcorrplot` and `cowplot`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(cowplot)

corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

p1 <- ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(corr, lab = TRUE)
p2 <- ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(corr, lab = TRUE)

cowplot::plot_grid(
  p1, p2,
  labels = "AUTO", ncol = 1
)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I was unaware of `ggcorrplot `.  In general, I also prefer `ggplot2` solutions. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If using `psych` package is your priority, you can take a look at `corrplot` library. The documentation can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/corrplot.pdf).

The code will look like this:

```
library(corrplot)

m <- cor(mtcars)
n <- cor(mtcars)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

corrplot(m)
corrplot(n)
```

And the output will look like this:
[image]

Comment: Actually I was trying to show comparison between `psych` and `corrplot`. There I was unable to show both of them together. Thank You for your response.